# Can I detect if the monitor is wide or Square and set Video accordingly?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made an flash presentation which runs in full screen there's animation of few second then a video start to plays and when the video end it goes to main menu.

The video is with 720x1080 (16:9) but My document in Flash is 768x576 (4:3).
I re-sized the video according 768x576, So at the top and bottom comes the black-bar. It is ok when my flash presentation runs on Square monitor, what if the Monitor is Wide.
and I want "action script" to detect of the type of monitor (Wide or Square) if its Square then it keep the video same but if the Monitor is wide then it start the video in full screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class, it has two properties, `screenResolutionX` and `screenResolutionY`, that will give you this information. This gives you the resolution of the primary screen.

You might want to rethink your assumption that a monitor is square. Screen resolutions are either 4:3 (640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024) or on my wide screen monitor some other ratio that is neither 4:3 nor square (1920x1080). You might want to do some research into what ratio wide screen monitors use (laptops might have a range of values).

Your code should query the Flash Player for the screen resolution:

```
var screenWidth:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var screenHeight:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

Then you can decide the appropriate time to switch to full screen or render the video at the regular size (768x576). I can think of a couple of ways to decide this, I'm sure you can too.

Here's some ideas in pseudo-code to get you thinking of an appropriate solution for your app:

```
if screen is not 4:3, assume wide screen and use full screen
if screenWidth >= actual width of video (1080), use full screen
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample script?

Comment: I thought and a simplest solution I can find is that There are lots of Monitor are coming into market with different Resolution like mine is 1600x900.... screen resolution are differ one company to other.
But one thing remains same is: Monitor is either Square or Wide.
it only need to detect this. I am researching on the "Capabilities" section..

Comment: Yes resolutions are very different. But your use of the word "square" is misleading. I've never seen monitors that have a "square" resolution where width and height are the same. The "square" resolution you refer to is really 4:3. You won't find anything in the `Capabilities` class that tells you whether the screen is 4:3 or "wide screen", so you will have to deduce that from the `screenResolutionX` and `screenResolutionY` values.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly in ActionScript but following is transcript of how your code should look like.

```
var nScreenWidth:Number =  Capabilities.screenResolutionX,
    nScreenHeight:Number = Capanilities.screenResolutionY;

var nVideoWidth:Number = video.source.getWidth(), //assuming you are using video class, this should be video native size and not video component size.
    nVideoHeight:Number = video.source.getHeight();

var nRatioX:Number = nVideoWidth / nScreenWidth,  //Calculating X and Y ratio of video source and screen.
    nRatioY:Number = nVideoHeight / nScreenHeight;

var nRatio:Number = Math.min(nRatioX, nRatioY); //Picking up smaller ratio so that we can fit video in screen.

video.width = Math.round(nScreenWidth * nRatio); //Set video component width and height, this should make it fit to screen keeping aspect ratio.
video.height = Math.round(nScreenHeight * nRatio);
```

Comment: I am not sure If my language was clear enough to explain what I wanted to say. I wish I could paste an image here.